# Prove $2^n < 3^n$ by induction

Tags: inequality, induction

How do I prove $2^n < 3^n$? 
I've done the base case and when $n=k$ but I don't know how to prove when $n = k+1$
Please help!

Comment: Can you write out what you would assume for the inductive step, and what you would need to show, using that assumption?

Comment: I see that you have asked a question, then hopefully go to bed (I have seen you are not active since then), waiting to "harvest the harvest" when awaking. This is not a good practice; it prevents from interaction with you... for example the question of @pjs36 asked 4 hours ago has no answer from you. I propose to close this question.

Comment: Moreover, it is nonsense to say in this context "I have **done** the base case for $n=k$"...

Answer (score 4):

The inductive hypothesis is $2^k < 3^k$. Then we have $2 < 3$ so $2\cdot 2^k < 3\cdot 3^k \iff 2^{k+1} < 3^{k+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

For the $n = k + 1 $ step:

$$2^{(k+1)} = 2^k \cdot 2$$

$$3^{(k+1)} = 3^k \cdot 3$$

We have $$2^k \cdot 2 < 3^k \cdot 3$$

By way of mathematical induction we can say $$2^n < 3^n \text{ for (insert your assumptions) }$$

Answer (score 0):

$3^{k+1}-2^{k+1}=3^k3-2^k2=3^k(2+1)-2^k2=2\underbrace{(3^k-2^k)}_{>0\text{ by induction}}+\underbrace{3^k}_{>0}>0$

Answer (score 0):

Base case $n=1$: $2\lt3$

Assume true for $n$:

$$2^n\lt3^n$$

$$2^{n+1}=2\cdot2^n\lt 2\cdot3^n\lt3\cdot3^n=3^{n+1}$$